# Giving a Boolean property to a controller object in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

After I drag a controller object to the document window, how do I give it a Boolean property?

Comment: The extra details you provided in the answers' comments make me think your question isn't really what you're trying to get an answer for.  If you can, try describing the exact behavior you're looking for.  Ignore properties, bindings, etc.  Just focus on something like, "Anytime a user checks a box, I want to do x,y,z."

This will help us steer you in the right direction.  I'm suspecting bindings may be more sophisticated than your needs merit.

Comment: Yeah I know bindings are more sophisticated than what I need. I just want a textbox to display a message indicating the status of a checkbox when the user clicks on the textbox. I've already done it without bindings. So now I want to try it with bindings so that I can understand how to do bindings.

Comment: Well, the problem with binding a checkbox to a text field/box is that the text that's going to appear in the field will be either 0 or 1 depending on the state of the checkbox.  Adding a boolean property to your controller won't help this.

To see this in action, create a new test project and in the window add a checkbox and textfield.  Then select the text field, go to the connections inspector and connect "takeStringValueFrom:" to the checkbox.  When you run the project, you'll see that toggling the checkbox does indeed change the text, but it's just 0 or 1....

Comment: When you're just starting out with bindings, my suggestion would be to stick to objects that represent the same type of data.  Perhaps a better exercise for you would be to populate a table view and then bind a text field to a column of the selected row of the table view.  Once you get the hang of that, you can try fancier stuff.

Comment: Now I'm just wondering whether I should delete my answer... it answers the question that was asked but does not reflect what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the ability to expose and edit the property *values* of your custom controller as attributes showing up in IB's inspector, you'll need to write your own plugin which tells IB what the inspector should look like.  This really can't be answered briefly.

Here's Apple's reference on IB Plugins:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004323-CH1-SW1

And here's the inspector portion:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/CreatingInspectors/CreatingInspectors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004323-CH6-SW1

If you truly just want to *add* a property to the controller's interface, you do this in Xcode (modifying the interface and implementation accordingly) and IB will pick up the changes automagically.

Comment: I just want to give it a Boolean property because I heard that's what needs to be done if I want to have a textbox write something in response to the user checking a checkbox using bindings. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a checkbox, the checkbox itself is either checked or not. That state stores the boolean value instead of the controller (unless you wish it.)

To have the app undertake an action upon clicking it, think of it as a button instead of a data display and link it to an action method in the view controller. That's the simplest and old school way of doing it.

To use binding, you need to bind the checkbox's `value` attribute to a controller. Usually for binary values its an object controller. So, in IB, drag an Object controller to your nib window  and bind it to your data source. Then, drag a checkmark button to the interface. In the checkmarks binding inspector. Set "value" binding to the name of the object controller, controller key to selection, keypath to the name of the data source attribute and provide a value transformer if needed.

Comment: Everything seems to make sense except the part about the data source. What data source? Do I have to type something in XCode to create it?

Comment: The datasource is whatever object you're using to manage your data model. It varies form app to app. If the app is simple it might just be a property in the view controller or a setting in user defaults. If the app is complex, then it could be Core Data, a SQL interface, download from a URL etc. That's only if you want to use binding. It sounds like you probably just want to treat the checkmark as a button and take an action when the user changes it.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how to do binding by making a simple example. I want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Actually, a boolean value is slightly more complicated because its not an object. Use a NSString.  instead. Just remember that you bind to a keypath that describe the path to a value inside an object or series of objects.